# The editor's link functionality illegaly changes content inside code blocks

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a new link to a post messes up the code already present in the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154936/adding-a-new-link-to-a-post-messes-up-the-code-already-present-in-the-post)

When adding / changing links in a post via the editor's "Hyperlink" button, the editor may renumber link references (e.g. if you insert a link at the top, it will have reference `[1]`, and other existing links will have their numbers increased).

The problem is this: The editor will do its renumbering magic even if the bracket-number-bracket combination is *inside a codeblock*. So if I have this:

```
This code does not work:

    myarr[3][1] = 7;

plz help people of [stackoverflow][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com
```

and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to insert a link at the top, the editor will not only add the link (and mysteriously duplicate the reference entry at the bottom), but also change the unrelated code:

```
This code from [the internet][1] does not work:

    myarr[3][2] = 7;

plz help people of [stackoverflow][3]


  [1]: http://google.com
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com
```

[This post on TeX.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96485) is an example of where a user seems to have fought with this problem (see the revision history).

Comment: Why is it that the only image that pops into my mind, when I see `[2][2]`, is a ballerina?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature! :-) The editor saw you inserted a new link at the top numbered `1`, and the rest of your link references were renumbered. And it is not very smart about that so all your `1` references where updated to `2`, etc.

Comment: @Martijn: Well yes, I know about this "feature"; I tried to describe it in my question. So I do _understand_ (but not _appreciate_) the change of the numbers. But why on earth did my link to TeX.se get duplicated?? I inserted only _two_ links, but now I have link numbers 1 to 3!

Comment: The parser is confused by the numbered 'links' that have no links. So a link reference was moved up slots in the array, moving from one, to two, to three as 'links' were reshuffled, but there was nothing moving up from 1 to 2 after it to overwrite things. That way you end up with duplicates.

Comment: @Martijn: Ah, thanks! Now I understand also this part.

Comment: To fix this, the parser should not go into code blocks.

Comment: Sorry for defacing your post, but it took me ten minutes to understand what the bug was that you were reporting. Please have a look at the edit to make sure you're okay with it.

Comment: @balpha: I was just about to edit the post myself because I saw that it's hardly understandable. I couldn't have put it better than you did, thank you very much!

Comment: @J. Steen: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: @balpha illegaly? Hope no charges will be pressed! ;-)