# Adding an image removes number-only links

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, images

**How to reproduce** (tested on StackOverflow and SuperUser):

1. Click "Ask question"
2. Enter text containing one or more numbered links, e.g.

   ```
   StackExchange-based websites ([1], [2]) are great, because ...

     [1]: http://stackoverflow.com
     [2]: http://serverfault.com
   ```
3. Put the cursor in the empty line before the links and use the "Insert Image" toolbar button to upload an image from your PC.

**Expected result**

The image is added as link `[3]`.

**Actual result**

The pre-existing links are removed:

```
StackExchange-based websites ([1], [2]) are great, because ...
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7OqX.png
```

**Notes**

This issue does not occur if the links are given a name instead of just a number:

```
StackExchange-based websites ([StackOverflow][1], [SuperUser][2]) are great, because ...
```

One could argue that the unnamed variant is an unsupported feature (it's not mentioned in the [markdown help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)). Still, it's not nice to remove something that the user has written.

Comment: Related: [Adding a new link to a post messes up the code already present in the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154936)