# Markdown editor messing with arrays of arrays

Tags: bug, markdown

Seems like the markdown editor is messing with arrays of arrays in code snippets.

Look at [this answer from Mike Bostock](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14691788/revisions):

```
(b[1][0] - b[0][0] and b[1][1] - b[0][1])
```

Was changed to:

```
(b[1][0] - b[0][0] and b[1][5] - b[0][6])
```

Weird and sometimes embarrassing for the volunteer.

Comment: Great job auto-linkifier, you broke something again!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a new link to a post messes up the code already present in the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154936/adding-a-new-link-to-a-post-messes-up-the-code-already-present-in-the-post)

Answer (score 6):

This happens when you have the existing arrays in place, at least one existing link, and then add an image or a link with the toolbar buttons.

Before adding image:

```
     a[0][1] b[0][1] c[0][1] d[0][1]

[1]: http://google.com
```

After adding image with toolbar button:

```
     a[0][1] b[0][2] c[0][3] d[0][4]

![enter image description here][5]

[1]: http://google.com
[2]: http://google.com
[3]: http://google.com
[4]: http://google.com
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JnEc.gif
```

In the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/184144#184144), plus [edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/184144/revisions).