# Editor feature renumbers link tags, making diffs in long posts hard to read

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, editor, diff

It is known that [the javascript-based post editor sometimes renumbers all Markdown format link identifiers in a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154936/222298), including identifiers of links that aren't even touched in an edit.

This causes some difficulty when another user edits (or suggests and edit for) a long post with many links, and later I try to review that edit.  Since many of the link identifiers will change, the side-by-side markdown diff will contain a lot of changes, and it's hard to see the real changes.  For an example, see revision 38 of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127/222298 .

It seems to me that changing existing link identifiers is unnecessary.  When adding a link, the editor should not modify existing links.  It should only find existing link identifiers like it does now, and generate a link identifier for the new link that is distinct from all the existing ones.  I would like to request that you change the editor so it does that.