# Stack Exchange automatically changing and breaking code when link updated?

Tags: feature-request, bug, markdown

I just asked 
[Multiline entries in custom toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330861/36296).

During editing I deleted an image and uploaded a new one. During this process the site automatically adjusted the numbers of links, `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

Unfortunately this happened inside a code block and thus changed a function and broke my MWE. I think it would be useful to exclude code blocks from such automatic replacements.

Comment: As far as I can tell, code blocks should *already be* excluded from such replacements. I have not been able to reproduce the issue you describe, not even using the exact code from your question.

Comment: Appears to be related to [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154936/adding-a-new-link-to-a-post-messes-up-indexes-in-square-brackets-in-code-already).